# marked.js not rendering image tags

Tags: javascript, javascript-marked

When I have a markdown file with:

```
![[20230613_110437.jpg]]
```

in it, and I render it to html with

`const html = marked.parse(content);`

the html content just contains ![[20230613_110437.jpg]] rather than the image tag.

Also, the image urls should be prefixed with `images/`, but I don't see a way to configure that.

How do I configure marked to convert this to:

```
<img src="images/20230613_110437.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`marked.js` does not parse image syntax in Markdown files by default.
To enable this feature, you can use the `renderer` option to customize the rendering of elements.

Try this configuration to parse image syntax and prefix image URLs with images/:

```js
const marked = require('marked');
const path = require('path');

const renderer = new marked.Renderer();
renderer.image = function(href, title, text) {
  // const url = href.startsWith('http') ? href : `images/${href}`; // for external links
  // return `<img src="${url}" alt="${text}" title="${title}" />`;

  const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, 'images', href);
  return `<img src="${imagePath}" src="${imagePath}" alt="${text}" title="${title}" />`; // for local references
};

const markdown = `![[20230613_110437.jpg]]`;
const html = marked(markdown, { renderer });

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if `![[20230613_110437.jpg]]` is an actual markdown. Why not just add images in the format of `![]()` like:

```markdown
![image](https://via.placeholder.com/200.png)
```

That renders to:

[image]`

```js
marked.use({
    headerIds: false,
    mangle: false,
});

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = marked.parse(`![image](https://via.placeholder.com/200.png)`);
console.log(marked.parse(`![image](https://via.placeholder.com/200.png)`));
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/5.1.0/marked.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```